# Installation steps for palaver speech on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-recognition

I tried installing [palaver speech recognition](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver) by the following the steps outlined [here](http://www.linuxveda.com/2013/03/19/how-to-install-linux-speech-recognition-in-ubuntu/) however I get error as shown here.

[image: Palaver-error]

I entered my firstname, lastname and email and language correctly in a popup.

What can I do to fix this error?

In addition I installed library python-notify as mentioned in github forum but to no avail.

Please help

Comment: Cool this question fetched me the tumbleweed badge

Comment: google closed the API